# bluecove - Send message to formerly unpaired device

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, message, pairing, bluecove

I have to send message from my (Ubuntu-12.04, 64-bit) laptop to a Bluetooth phone whose friendly name is provided as an argument. This phone may or may not have connected/paired with the laptop earlier. I am using the Java code as shown here to send a message from my laptop to the Bluetooth device.

```
package com.test.bt;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException;
import javax.bluetooth.DiscoveryAgent;
import javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.RemoteDevice;
import javax.bluetooth.UUID;

public class BluetoothTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            BluetoothStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
        BluetoothDiscoveryListener bdl = new BluetoothDiscoveryListener();

        LocalDevice ld = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
        DiscoveryAgent da = ld.getDiscoveryAgent();
        da.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, bdl);
        bdl.doLock();

        UUID[] uuidSet = new UUID[1];
        uuidSet[0] = new UUID(0x1105); // OBEX Object Push service
        int[] attrSet = new int[] { 0x0100 }; // Service name

        boolean deviceFound = false;
        for (RemoteDevice rd : bdl.remoteDevices) {
            if (rd.getFriendlyName(false).matches(args[0])) {
                deviceFound = true;
                da.searchServices(attrSet, uuidSet, rd, bdl);
                bdl.doLock();

                bdl.sendMessage("Bluetooth.txt", "text", args[1]);
            }
        }
        if (!deviceFound) {
            System.err.println("Requested device was not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

It works only when the device has formerly paired. Else, it fails as shown below. Actually, I get a prompt on my phone if the PIN mathces and I say Yes. And, then, this failure below.

```
BlueCove version 2.1.0 on bluez
Device Phone found at address 101DC0F72211
    MAJOR device class 512
    MINOR device class 4
    MAJOR service classes 5898240
Inquiry completed successfully.
Following services are found ... 
     Service name : OPP
      URL is : btgoep://101DC0F72211:3;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false
Services search completed successfully.
Connecting to btgoep://101DC0F72211:3;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to connect. [115] Operation now in progress
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.connectionRfOpenClientConnectionImpl(Native Method)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.connectionRfOpenClientConnection(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:560)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.<init>(BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.java:37)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openImpl(MicroeditionConnector.java:387)
    at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.open(MicroeditionConnector.java:162)
    at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:83)
    at com.test.bt.BluetoothDiscoveryListener.sendMessage(BluetoothDiscoveryListener.java:106)
    at com.test.bt.BluetoothTest.main(BluetoothTest.java:52)
BlueCove stack shutdown completed
```

I tried variation of authentication and encryption options; but, no luck.

Even when the device had already paired, I noticed another behavior that I am not understanding. If the device had paired successfully, I was thinking I could use the `retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.CACHED)` method or the `retrieveDevices(DiscoveryAgent.PREKNOWN)` method. Both return null.

So, how do I send a message to such a phone that hadn't earlier paired with the laptop ?